# CSS Module: &.className

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, css-in-js

Is it possible to do something like this with `CSS Modules`?

**CSS**

```
.dateLabel {
  text-align: center;

  &.today {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
import s from './style.scss';

return (
    <div class={`today ${s.dateLabel}`}>
     ...         
);
```

Because I would like to **avoid** doing like this:

```
.dateLabel {
  text-align: center;
}

.today {
  background: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
import s from './style.scss';

return (
    <div class={`${s.today} ${s.dateLabel}`}>
     ...         
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `sass Ampersnad` to achieve this.

```
https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/
```

Comment: Yea that's what I'm doing as seen in the code snippet above, but it doesn't seem to take effect with `css module`.